umqtt doesn't recognize when it loses connection to AWS w/ SSL
I'm putting together an IoT device with MQTT and AWS. The current version of the device connects to AWS IoT Core with umqtt.simple with SSL. It connects just fine, but after 1-2 minutes it stops receiving updates from the broker. The LED keeps blinking indicating that client.check_msg() is running without exception, but it doesn't receive updates. client.disconnect() is never called.
I have keepalive set to 60sec and I've tried umqtt.simple and umqtt.robust. Robust is supposed to have automatic reconnect built in, but it's not working here. It doesn't seem to recognize when the connection is dead.
The first version connected to Adafruit IO using MQTT with username/password. The MQTT broker connection never lasted more than a few minutes, but a simple while/try/except got it to reconnect very reliably and it stayed functional for days at a time.
Any idea why it doesn't know when it's disconnected? Why keepalive=60 has no effect? main.py is here:
import device, lib.keys as keys, machine, network, ntptime, lib.robust as robust, ssl, time, ubinascii

MQTT_CLIENT_ID = ubinascii.hexlify(machine.unique_id())

led = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)

def read_pem(file):
    with open(file, "r") as input:
        text = input.read().strip()
        split_text = text.split("\n")
        base64_text = "".join(split_text[1:-1])
        return ubinascii.a2b_base64(base64_text)
        
def led_pulse(n):
    half_pulse = 0.1
    for i in range(0,n):
        led.on()
        time.sleep(half_pulse)
        led.off()
        time.sleep(half_pulse)
    time.sleep(0.5)

def internet_connect():
    print("Connecting to WiFi ...")
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(keys.WIFI_SSID, keys.WIFI_PASSWORD)
    while not wlan.isconnected():
        led_pulse(2)
    print("Connected to WiFi\n")

def mqtt_callback(topic, msg):
    topic_str = topic.decode()
    msg_str = msg.decode()
    print(f"RX: {topic_str}\t{msg_str}")
    for command in device.commands:
        if msg_str == command[0]:
            led.on()
            command[1]()

def mqtt_setup():
    key = read_pem(keys.MQTT_CLIENT_KEY)
    cert = read_pem(keys.MQTT_CLIENT_CERT)
    ca = read_pem(keys.MQTT_BROKER_CA)
    mqtt_client = robust.MQTTClient(
        client_id = MQTT_CLIENT_ID,
        server = keys.MQTT_BROKER,
        keepalive = 60,
        ssl = True,
        ssl_params = {
            "key": key,
            "cert": cert,
            "server_hostname": keys.MQTT_BROKER,
            "cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
            "cadata": ca,
        },
    )
    mqtt_client.set_callback(mqtt_callback)
    return mqtt_client

def mqtt_connect(client):
    print("Connecting to MQTT Broker ...")
    led_pulse(3)
    client.connect()
    led_pulse(4)
    client.subscribe(keys.MQTT_TOPIC)
    print("Connected to MQTT Broker\n")

def mqtt_listen(client):
    print(f"Listening to {keys.MQTT_TOPIC} ...")
    while True:
        client.check_msg()
        led_pulse(1)

def mqtt_disconnect(client):
    print("Disconnecting from MQTT Broker ...")
    client.disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from MQTT Broker\n")

while True:
    internet_connect()
    ntptime.settime()
    mqtt_client = mqtt_setup()
    try:
        mqtt_connect(mqtt_client)
        mqtt_listen(mqtt_client)
    except:
        mqtt_disconnect(mqtt_client)


Update:
I modified main.py to manually disconnect and reconnect every minute and that worked just fine, except it's disconnected for five seconds out of every minute.
Then I modified it to publish a message every few seconds and so far it's stayed alive and connected for the past 30minutes.
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
while True:
    internet_connect(wlan)
    ntptime.settime()
    mqtt_client = mqtt_setup()
    mqtt_connect(mqtt_client)
    while wlan.isconnected():
        for i in range(0, 20):
            mqtt_client.check_msg()
            led_pulse(1)
        mqtt_client.publish(keys.MQTT_TOPIC, "poke")


Setting keepalive = 60 means the server will expect to receive a Control Packet (generally a PUBLISH or PINGREQ) every 60 seconds. umqtt is pretty minimal and does not handle sending the PINGREQ for you (so it's unsurprising the connection is dropping). You can call ping() to send a PINGREQ but the functionality is fairly minimal (see PR's #332, #586 etc). Robust may take a while to detect loss of connection.

Leaving keepalive unset gave me the same behavior. Manually publishing a message every 30 seconds seems to keep the connection alive for hours, at least so far.

Sorry - my comment aimed to inform you why adding keepalive = 60 would not help (because umqtt does not sent pings automatically regardless of the setting). I suspect you are hitting a TCP idle timeout of some kind (so calling ping() would probably help too).
